# Database description language with converter backends?

Tags: database, programming, documentation-generator, code-generation

I develop on a project that failed in the first run (without me) because the database was getting more and more inconsistent, having been defined ambiguously and never documented officially. A new attempt should start from scratch.

I am looking for some kind of database description language with a converter and a number of conversion backends:

- LaTeX und HTML docs
- possibly ER diagrams (nice, but not required)
- Relationship diagrams
- Data declarations for C and Java
- SQL statements for creating and updating the database structures (for different databases, preferably at least MySQL)
- Code for integrity checking
- Code for CRUD functions

I have written such a converter long time ago (probably like everybody else) but it wasn‘t very nifty and got quickly unreadable with longer description texts. There must be something better! Who knows where?